# turn range of arraylist into string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an arraylist with the size 0 or .. any size. And I want to turn anything inside into string list. So, suppose the arraylist has the size of 10 and I only want the first 5 elements of it. Instead of doing a for loop, any other efficient method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method:

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one","two","three","four"));
List<String> sub = s.subList(0,2); //["one","two"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
List<String> stringList = intList.stream().map(i -> i.toString())
        .limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(stringList);
```

I'm not sure whether I understood your question correctly, but this way, you can turn anything into a list of strings first and limit it thereafter.